# Macro to Insert blank rows in excel between each record in a data set of varying # or records.

Tags: excel, insert, row, vba

I create numerous files each month that range from 20-10,000 rows.  One field is a varying lenght, formatted as wrapped text to allow it to fit 1 page wide for reporting.  Since the file is used to generate a report for outside users I have inserting a blank row between each record so the text doesn't run together.  I need a way to write a macro that will allow me to insert blank rows from row 2 to row x (where x would be anywhere from 20 to 10,000).

Answer (score 0):

Like this .. do this in your button

```
Sub InsertRow()

    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).EntireRow.Resize(100).Insert

End Sub
```

This will insert 100 blank rows